# Pentaho initialization Exception: ERROR_0014 EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener

Tags: postgresql, pentaho

I am getting Pentaho Initialization exception when try to connect to user console. There is some problem with Quartz database I have created in Postgresql. I followed the steps to setup Postgresql repository referring the url http://blog.endpoint.com/2013/11/install-pentaho-bi-server-48-community.html

I also checked Catalina logs but to couldn't find anything relevant.

Here's what the page says:

**The following errors were detected
One or more system listeners failed. These are set in the systemListeners.xml.
   org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener
Please see the server console for more details on each error detected.**

Comment: More context is required. Include a bigger section of the logs, please. The error message in itself only says what isn't working, but doesn't shed any light as to why it's not working.

Comment: I installed jackrabbit database in Postgresql and stumbled upon another error related to SecuritySystemListener.                       Here's logs for your reference:                                             org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.security.userrole.SecuritySystemListener                                                            It is defined in the systemlisteners.xml file. I now get 404.

Comment: a 4 or 5 line snipper of logs is not nearly enough. The stack trace on your log files (catalina.out and pentaho.log) is HUGE and that's where the information is. Read them, you'll find your answer.

Comment: I will dig into the issue. Thank you.